# How to support Cyrillic characters in an Android custom keyboard

Tags: java, android-studio, custom-keyboard, cyrillic

I'm trying to make a custom keyboard for android that supports Cyrillic characters and I'm missing a step but can't figure it out.  I have read that ASCII characters 128-255 aren't naturally supported.  What do I need to do in order to support these extended ASCII characters.  Any links to read on material or help is appreciated!

This is where I found out about the extended ASCII character set.

https://www.ascii-codes.com/cp866.html